# Sitecore defined Languages appearing in "More Languages" dialogue form

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore7.2

Where I can find the `system` defined list of `languages` appearing in the "`More Languages`" button option?

[image]]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, and follow the instruction that how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sitecore 7.2 they are defined in `"/App_Config/LanguageDefinitions.config"` file.

If you're wondering if anything was overriden by any other config patch file, check `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` to see the list. They are in `/sitecore/languageDefinitions/languages` node.

What you see in the list is the (e.g. `Arabic (Saudi Arabia) : العربية (المملكة العربية السعودية`) is the .net `CultureInfo` `EnglishName` and `NativeName` based on `id` and `region` defined in the config file mentioned above.

Comment: I was wondering how the Language id and the region helps to show up the text like "Arabic (Saudi Arabia) : العربية (المملكة العربية السعودية)"